# Ошибка в подключении jQuery

Tags: jquery

Хотел подключить jQuery, но выдает массу ошибок, как исправить не знаю ,скрины прилагаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: Пробуйте может... `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Я пробовал и сжатую и как показано на скринах не сжатую,результат один

Comment: Подключил вроде правильно пользуюсь brackets из за этого может быть проблема? Хотя и в соблайме такая же история,вот в чем проблема!?!?